# Integrate QGIS Plugin with Java Project

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, java, python-2.7

I  have a Java Application. I am using QGIS to solve one such module of my Java Application. I have written code in python console within QGIS.Is there any way to integrate both of these?
I am thinking to create a plugin and then call this plugin from My Java application . The output File is .csv (and not shape Files). Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible, but is never easy and it maybe requires a deep understanding about programming, QGIS source. Generally speaking, a java program can invoke C/C++ native module(function) through JNI(Java Native Interface). let's suppose you are developing such C++ module(or plugin) . And then the C++ plugin should be built on based on QGIS libraries and support Python binding. [here](https://github.com/Wujingli/PythonSupportSample) is a my simple sample about python binding. All required skill: Java/ JNI tech, C++/Qt/QGIS/PyQGIS/Sip.

Comment: Hi, can't I use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097491/call-and-receive-output-from-python-script-in-java

Comment: That is nearly impossible.
Answser you have seen is about how to execute pure python script in Java standalone application.
You should correctly understand what is QGIS python plugin.
QGIS python plugin is quite diffrent from pure python script. That is not standalone.
That can be executed under the condition a QGIS instance was loaded. That is why we call it "Plugin".
You can identify so called "iface" variable in some QGIS Python plugin script source.
This variable refers to QGIS instance.
Hope this is helpful for your understanding.

Comment: Any other approach ?